# Worklight Server Compatibility

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

So, if the answer to this question is 'no they aren't compatible' then this is an easy one to close. Basically, I am using the encrypted cache in a WL app which is made using WL 6.1.0 inside of Eclipse. Now, I've deployed this to my external WL server, however, this WL server is running 5.0.6.20130311-0918. So, my first question is, does this app have ANY chance of working? I'm not sure on backward compatibility.

To help with the above, the error I see when I try to access my application on the server is as follows:

```
Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.getOrCreateAuthenticationContext():106' 

   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.getOrCreateAuthenticationContext(AuthenticationContext.java:106)
   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:105)
```

Is this simply due to the incompatibility? I'm unable to get my encrypted cache to work as it needs to connect to my server one time only - this is where I'm stuck.

And my final question - does the war file have to be exactly the same as the name of the app? In my case it isn't, see below. Is this a problem? Surely not.

```
<application id="RedHand" name="RedHand" location="MyRedHand.war" type="war">
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your server and studio versions match in order to work properly together in older versions of Worklight. Here is a technote that describes this requirement:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21609785

It specifically states the following:

"Some runtime issues have been observed when running different version numbers of Worklight Server and Worklight Studio. Features and/or upgrades which were released in one version of Worklight may not be compatible in older environment versions. Both the Server and Studio versions must be the same in order to utilize all upgrades and features across both environments."

This being said I believe there are some backwords compatibility between running older version applications in 6.1 server. Below I will link the infocenter section that describes this as well as highlight the corresponding text:

https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc%2Fdevenv%2Fc_upgrade_to_srvr610_separation_of_server_and_studio.html

"In version 6.1.0, IBM Worklight allows a separation between the Worklight Server and Worklight Studio lifecycles. This separation means

- It is possible to upgrade an instance of Worklight Server to version 6.1.0 without upgrading your existing applications to Worklight Studio version 6.1.0.
- It is possible to deploy project WAR files, apps, and adapters that are developed with any supported version of Worklight Studio (V5.0.6.x, V6.0.0.x, and V6.1.0) to an instance of Worklight Server V6.1.0. But the apps that are deployed must be built with the same version of Worklight Studio as the project WAR file that was previously deployed. As an example, consider a Worklight project that was developed on Worklight Studio V5.0.6, and this project's WAR file is later deployed on Worklight Server V6.1.0. This WAR file is deployed as a V5.0.6 project, without having been opened in Worklight Studio V6.1.0. You can later deploy to this Worklight project only applications and adapters that were developed using Worklight Studio V5.0.6 (and not V6.1.0 or any other version).

Some limitations of this lifecycle separation are as follows:

- Only application environments that are supported by Worklight Server V6.1.0 can be migrated. Older application environments that are not supported by Worklight Server V6.1.0 (for example, iGoogle, Windows Phone 7.5, or Facebook) will no longer be available after the server upgrade.
- To deploy a project WAR file, you must use the tools that are provided with the target Worklight Server version you are deploying to. That is, to deploy with an Ant task to Worklight Server, you must use the worklight-ant-deployer.jar file that is located in the WorklightServer directory of the Worklight Server installation directory."

The issue with your current configuration is you are trying to accomplish the opposite, trying to run a 6.1 application on a 5.0.6 server which is not supported. In my opinion you should upgrade your server to match your studio version.

In regards to your second question I do not believe the war name has to be the same as your application as long as you have the new name configured correctly in your server side configuration.