# Worklight 6.1.0.2 app on Server 6.1.0.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

Does anybody know whether Worklight version 6.1.0.2 which has support for iOS also requires a server upgrade? Or will it work on Server 6.1.0.1 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worklight 6.1.0.1 and Worklight 6.1.0.2 are both Worklight 6.1.0.x.

Meaning that they are the same, where the only difference being that 6.1.0.2 contains more fixes (it is  6.1 Fix Pack 2). Worklight guarantees that nothing should break between fix packs.

So, you can run an application created in Worklight Studio version 6.1.0.2 on a Worklight Server version 6.1.0.1, because both are 6.1*, but if you ask me... because there are fixes in both the server and studio, if you have the opportunity to upgrade both, then you should do that. You can review the list of fixes for 6.1.0.2 [in this page](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27041452).

---

Also, already-deployed applications should continue to work even if upgrading the server, but apps created with newer Studio versions cannot work on older Server versions.

You can read more here: [Worklight Server Compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019946/worklight-server-compatibility)

Comment: Thanks @Idan. We're looking to add support for iOS8 which is why I'm asking. Server upgrade is looking unlikely due to tight timeframes and is likely we'll go straight to 6.2 when we decide to upgrade.